# How to use scalar variable in XML Path query SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to pass table name into into a scalar variable `@Table_Name` as a string. But I am getting error as:

> Must declare the table variable @Table_Name.

How to achieve the same? Below is my code snippet:

```
Declare @Table_Name as varchar(200);
SET @Table_Name = 'Table_name'
SET @sql = '(SELECT' + STUFF((SELECT *
                                FROM @Table_Name
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' )
               + ' FROM SomeOtherTable'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created a temporary table using the input provided by the user and used that temp table in the query. Following is a code snippet:

```
Declare @Table_Name as varchar(200);
Declare @sql as nvarchar(max);
SET @Table_Name = 'Table_name'
SET @sql = 'select * into ##TempTable from '+ @Table_Name

SET @sql = '(SELECT' + STUFF((SELECT *
                                FROM ##TempTable
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' )
               + ' FROM SomeOtherTable'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the variable before using it.

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
SET @sql = '(SELECT STUFF((SELECT *
                            FROM '+ @Table_Name + 
                            ' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' )'
           + ' FROM SomeOtherTable';
```

Comment: This does not work. Throws the same error. Look at my edited code snippet.

Comment: you have to conatenate the variable, as I have done

Answer (score 0):

The statement `SELECT * FROM @Table_Name` executes correctly, when `@Table_Name` is a table variable. In your case you need to use a dynamic statement and fix syntax errors in the statement (additional `(` before the first `SELECT`):

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = N'YourTable'
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT STUFF((SELECT * FROM ',
    QUOTENAME(@TableName),
    ' FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 1, N'''') FROM SomeOtherTable'
)

PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```